Azure SQL -- How can i list the "Azure SQL" PaaS servers enabled with exception ( Under networking
I have tried to get the information of Azure Sql PaaS service enabled with exception . But unable to retrieve the info.
resources
| where type contains "microsoft.sql/servers/databases"

But unable to see the networkig info in Properties

Could you please provide what you have tried?

The properties of "microsoft.sql/servers" will have below fields.
{
  "publicNetworkAccess": "***",
  "privateEndpointConnections": [],
  "state": "**",
  "version": "**",
  "restrictOutboundNetworkAccess": "***",
  "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "***.database.windows.net",
  "minimalTlsVersion": "***",
  "externalGovernanceStatus": "***",
  "administratorLogin": "***"
}

In order to check if the server is enabled with exception under networking, you can filter the rows with publicNetworkAccess is not equal to "Enabled".
Code:
Resources
| where type == "microsoft.sql/servers"
| extend publicNetworkAccess = properties.publicNetworkAccess
| where publicNetworkAccess != "Enabled"

